# React JS - how to remove added items array object using index key on usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem. When i select and delete some of array object added on usestate. it's not deleting the selected. i don't know why. the slice method is working fine when i console log it. the selected index is correct. but when i update the usestate array object the selected index is not working. the only working is the last index deleted.

here is the some of example. i selected and remove the **`orange`** but it's not removing the last item `guava` was removed not the orange i select.

[image]

Here is usestate **benefits** array object :

```
const [benefits, setBenefits] = useState([{name:''}])
```

Here is my onChange **handlerDescription**

```
const handlerDescription = (index,e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        let temp = [...benefits]
        temp[index] = e.target.value
        setBenefits(temp)

      //all value will store here
 }
```

Here is my onClick **handlerCloseRow**

```
const handlerCloseRow = (index) => {
    const newItems = [...benefits]; // create a copy of the array
    newItems.splice(index, 1); // remove the item at the specified index
    setBenefits(newItems); // update the state with the updated array
};
```

Here is my onClick **handlerAddRow**

```
 const handlerAddRow = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setBenefits([...benefits,{
            name:''
        }])
     }
```

Here is my code. the **handlerAddrow** is not inside on **`MAP method`**

```
 <section>
    <label>
    Description
    </label>
    {benefits.map((benefit,index)=>(
        <div key={index} className="mb-4">
            <Input onChange={(e)=>handlerDescription(index,e)} value={benefits?.name} type="text" />
            <button onClick={(e)=>handlerCloseRow(index,benefit,e)}>close</button>
        </div>
    ))}
    <div  onClick={handlerAddRow}>
    <button className="text-3xl"/><span>Add Row</span>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to remove one element from the state's array you can create a temporary array with the new array:

```
 const deleteHandler = (index) => {
    const newCardList = [...cards];
    newCardList.splice(index, 1);
    setCards(newCardList);
  };
```

You can test it on this example I prepared: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qjhr8l?file=App.tsx

Comment: thank you. your answered help me well i just inserted the INPUT text in the card.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to save a `benefit` as an object, you may modify the `handlerDescription` like this.

```
const handlerDescription = (index, e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let temp = [...benefits];
  temp[index] = { name: e.target.value };
  setBenefits(temp);
};
```

Also, in the map operation, each input value should be `benefit.name` instead of `benefits?.name`.

```
{benefits.map((benefit, index) => (
  <div key={index} className="mb-4">
    <Input
      onChange={(e) => handlerDescription(index, e)}
      value={benefit.name}
      type="text"
    />
    <button onClick={(e) => handlerCloseRow(index, benefit, e)}>
      close
    </button>
  </div>
))}
```

Hope it may help.

Comment: thank you but i did the same way you typed. nothing changed